# Green's function in a moving frame for a constant heat source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

I am looking for the Green's function of the problem in two dimensions $r =(x,z)$,
\begin{equation}
 \nabla^2g + \frac{v}{D}\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = -\delta (r-r_0)
\end{equation}

Which corresponds to finding temperature distribution in a moving frame (moving at constant velocity $v$ in $z$ direction and diffusion coefficient of the medium is $D$) because of the constant source and $|r-r_0| = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$

[research paper](http://juwel.fz-juelich.de:8080/dspace/bitstream/2128/3023/1/Saito_1988.Numerical.pdf) gives solution as,

\begin{eqnarray}
g(r,r_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{z-z_1}{l} \right)K_0\left(\frac{|r-r_0|}{l} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Where, $K_0$ is a modified Bessel function of second kind and $l = \frac{2D}{v}$. How can one arrive at this solution? I tried to varify the solution but I could not go anywhere close.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial g(r,r_0)}{\partial z} &=& \exp\left(-\frac{z-z_1}{l} \right)\left[- \frac{1}{l}K_0 + \frac{\partial K_0}{\partial z} \right]\\
\frac{\partial^2 g(r,r_0)}{\partial z^2} &=& \exp\left(-\frac{z-z_1}{l} \right)\left[ \frac{1}{l^2}K_0 -\frac{2}{l} \frac{\partial K_0}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial^2 K_0}{\partial z^2}\right] \\
\frac{\partial^2 g(r,r_0)}{\partial x^2} &=& \exp\left(-\frac{z-z_1}{l} \right)\left[  \frac{\partial^2 K_0}{\partial x^2}\right]
\end{eqnarray}

then putting the terms together,
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^2g + \frac{2}{l}\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} &=& \exp\left(-\frac{z-z_1}{l} \right)\left[\frac{\partial^2 K_0}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 K_0}{\partial z^2} -\frac{1}{l^2}K_0 \right]
\end{eqnarray}

rhs of the equation should be zero unless $r=r_0$.

possible [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) of $K_0$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
K_0([r-r_0]/l) &=& \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\cos([r-r_0] \frac{u}{l})}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} du \\
&=& \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2} \frac{u}{l})}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} du
\end{eqnarray}

rhs is then,
\begin{eqnarray}
rhs &=& -\exp\left(-\frac{z-z_1}{l} \right)\left[ \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\frac{1+u^2}{l^2}\cos([r-r_0] \frac{u}{l}) + \frac{u}{l(r-r_0)}\sin([r-r_0] \frac{u}{l})}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} du \right]
\end{eqnarray}

Which I do not see how is equal to $\delta(r-r_0)$. What am I missing here?